# How to submit watchOS2 app without an iPhone app?

Tags: xcode, swift, app-store-connect, watchkit, watchos-2

I created an app for watchOS 2. So, How can I submit **only** the watchOS 2 app to iTunes? Which bundleID should be used for submitting the app?

com.name.appname.watchkitapp
 
com.name.appname.extension
com.name.appname

Which one should i choose? What is the submitting process for **only** watchOS2 app?

Answer (score 2):

You can't submit Apple Watch apps without a corresponding iPhone app.  You are required to have an iPhone app for any watch app you submit to the Apple App store.

(All three of the bundles you mention are required for submitting a Watch app...)